# How or where can I ask about vendor providing system apps?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to buy a new android device and do not want to root it. But I need some functions. These functions can only be provided - on a non-rooted device if they are provided as system app.

So I end up with a quetion about  which veendor provides me with system apps, providiing the needed functions (app-data backup, local contacts, local calendar and autostart-manager). Is this completely off topic here,  or is there a stack-exchangee-site where this would be on topic?

Comment: It would be off-topic per the [help/on-topic]. Perhaps this may help: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371) Maybe a question on [Hardware Recommendations](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: @Firelord I will try Hardware Recom. Make that an answer to my question, so I can accept it...

Comment: @Firelord if you're going to link to Hardware Recs, please read our help center first, and link to that rather than the site itself.

Comment: Hardware Recommendations will not have questions about *vendors*, but it will take questions about specific devices.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: Sure, will take care of that next time. On your point about not having this question on your site, *all Android phones comes with a full featured OS* (alike PCs you can't buy a new Android phone without the OS) and OP is looking for a hardware with specific software features. Given the question quality link tell me why is the question not on-topic on your site? When it comes to Android smartphones, you can't have software and hardware treated separately. Do you have a policy (meta post) on that or does it simply not matter to you?

Comment: @Firelord the question is on topic on HR. We've already got it. I was making a slightly different point that questions specifically about vendors are off topic; the question in question (heh) has enough detail to be asking set a specific device.